# RecycleView sorting

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, view

For some time I have been struggling with the problem of sorting information in `RecycleView`, the data comes from Firebase, I would like to sort single row depending on one of the objects from a class. maybe the code will explain it better.

```
private fun fetchHours(){
        var link = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/WorkTime/$link")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()

                p0.children.forEach {
                    Log.d("Vievactivity", it.toString())
                    var singlerow = it.getValue(CounterActivity.WorkTimeCountedClass::class.java)
                    if (singlerow != null ){
                        adapter.add(WorkTimeList(singlerow))
                    }
                }
                recycleViev_list.adapter = adapter

                adapter.setOnItemClickListener{ item, view ->

                    val useruuid = item as WorkTimeList
                    val intent = Intent(view.context, EditDataActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(CLICKED_ITEM_KEY, useruuid.naz.uuid)
                    startActivity(intent)

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
}
class WorkTimeList(var naz: CounterActivity.WorkTimeCountedClass): Item<GroupieViewHolder>(){
    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.itemView.row_viewactivity_invisible_uuid.text = naz.uuid
        viewHolder.itemView.Row_viewactivity_employer.text = naz.employer
        viewHolder.itemView.Row_viewactivity_StartWork.text = naz.startTimeString
        viewHolder.itemView.Row_viewactivity_StopWork.text = naz.stopTimeString
        viewHolder.itemView.imageView_planTime.text = naz.planedTimeToSpendAtWorkString
        viewHolder.itemView.imageView_complitedTime.text = naz.totalTimeSpendAtworkString
        viewHolder.itemView.imageView_overHours.text = naz.overHoursString
    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.row_viewactivity
    }
}
```

as a result, he gets something like that
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo7Jo.png)

I would like individual rows to be sorted depending on user preference, for example ascending from the variable `viewHolder.itemView.Row_viewactivity_StartPracy.text = naz.startTimeString` or descending from `viewHolder.itemView.imageView_complitedTime.text = name. TotalTime` Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/WorkTime/$link")
    ref.orderByChild("order").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()

            p0.children.forEach {
                Log.d("Vievactivity", it.toString())
                var singlerow = it.getValue(CounterActivity.WorkTimeCountedClass::class.java)
                if (singlerow != null ){
                    adapter.add(WorkTimeList(singlerow))
                }
            }
            recycleViev_lista.adapter = adapter
```

I found a solution, maybe just writing the first question here inspired me :)

So using "orderByChild" I added sorting, unfortunately only increasing sorting works. To change this I came up with the idea that the value after which I want to sort subtract from 0 - it will reverse the sorting method :)

I am not good at explaining, so maybe for example:
Writes to the Firebase start time in milliseconds for example (1579097163159), (1578374795583), (1579152252463) - sorting this data we get the result in increasing

```
1 - (1578374795583)
2 - (1579097163159)
3 - (1579152252463)
```

Unfortunately, I did not find how to change orderByChaild tabs so that they sort in descending order ...... we can subtract from these values ​​and get the expected effect:

```
1 - (1578374795583) -> 0 - 1578374795583 = - 1578374795583
2 - (1579097163159) -> 0 - 1579097163159 = - 1579097163159
3 - (1579152252463) -> 0 - 1579152252463 = - 1579152252463
```

We need to add a variable to Firebase, which will be the result of this operation, we then sort by the result of this operation and it's ready.

```
1 - 1579152252463
2 - 1579097163159
3 - 1578374795583
```

I hope I helped someone as much as I can't count how many times I found help here. Regards